# Function literal with receiver in Kotlin

Tags: lambda, kotlin, receiver

I'm trying a function literal with receiver example in kotlin, based on this tutorial:
https://kotlinexpertise.com/coping-with-kotlins-scope-functions/

I'm expecting to get 3 back from the code below, but it seems the Int method dec() isn't executed or the "mint" variable isn't updated.

```
fun summer(block: Int.() -> Unit): Int{
     var myint = 5
    myint.block()
    return myint
    }
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var mint = summer{
        dec()
        dec()
     }
    println(mint)
}
```

The output here is '5'.

Can anyone offer some suggestions about how to get this "simple" example working?

Comment: I think it's because dec() is an operator that returns the value but does not change the object itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Author of this article here. Your `summer` function's `block` function does not return anything, you should change the type to `block: Int.() -> Int` and then return its response:

```
fun summer(block: Int.() -> Int): Int {
    val myint = 5
    return myint.block()
}
```

Now, your printed integer would be `4`, because the last `dec()` will become the result of the passed lambda. To fix this, you could chain both `dec` calls:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val mint = summer {
        dec().dec()
    }
    println(mint)
}
```

Finally, `5` will be decremented twice resulting in `3`.

If, on the other hand, you had some arbitrary object that is being mutated by a `dec` function, your approach would work like this:

```
class Ref(var v: Int) {
    fun dec() {
        v -= 1
    }
}

fun summer(block: Ref.() -> Unit): Int {
    val ref = Ref(5).apply(block)
    return ref.v
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val mint = summer {
        dec()
        dec()
    }
    println(mint)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`inc()` and `dec()` do not mutate the object they are invoked on. Instead they return a mutated copy of the object:

Does not work:

```
var a = 5
a.inc()
println(a) // 5
```

Works:

```
var a = 5
a = a.inc()
println(a) // 6
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because dec() is an operator and does not modify the the underlying value.
For example you you run this code,  you should see that i never changes, note the use of val not var,  in your example Idea should be giving you a hint.
If you wrap the Int in a class you can see how the function with a receiver works.

```
data class Foo(var i:Int) {
    fun dec() {
        i = i.dec()
    }
}


fun summer(block: Foo.() -> Unit): Foo{
    val myint = Foo(5)
    myint.block()
    return myint


}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val i = 42
    println("i = $i")  // i = 42
    val j = i.dec()   
    println("j = $j")  // i = 41
    println("i = $i")  // i = 42

    val x = summer {
        dec()
        dec()
    }
    println(x)  // Foo(i=3)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the explanation in the documentation about [operators](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#increments-and-decrements):

> The `inc()` and `dec()` functions must return a value, which will be assigned to the variable on which the `++` or `--` operation was used. They shouldn't mutate the object on which the `inc` or `dec` was invoked.

So essentially, calls using the operators like this:

```
x++
y--
```

Would be translated to this in terms of the `inc`/`dec` functions:

```
x = x.inc()
y = y.dec()
```

---

Bonus finding: using intention actions on these functions or operators lets you convert between the two forms, but does so erroneously (changes behavior, might even break compilation). There's an issue open for this here.